# Get xpath element in flexbox

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, flexbox

If I click the chrome extension it open a window (flex) I can inspect it but I can't interact with it.

If I try its xpath and assert it , it always fails. I think I need to switch to it first then assert it. Like we for iframes.

Xpath I tried was `"//button[text()='Merge']"`. Click on the image to see clearly.

[image]

How can I verify it? If not selenium can I assert it in JavaScript maybe? I don't know how do it in JS

Comment: Where / how can I see this window?

Comment: This is chrome extension and it is not live I can't share this. If I paste HTML will that work?

Comment: I'm not sure, sorry

Comment: You can try with this chrome extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/table-capture/iebpjdmgckacbodjpijphcplhebcmeop/related?hl=en, it gives similar kind of pop up and locators in this pop can't be verified.

Comment: I found this, but don't know how to implement https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/automating-flex-application-selenium-webdriver-himanshu-tewari

Comment: Well, I'm not familiar with this...

Comment: Are you using webdriverwaits here?  Include the whole line of code with the assert.

Comment: @paul Have you tried by switching windows?

Comment: @paul : What is the error you get when you tried this xpath `//button[text()='Merge']` ? also is that open in new tab ?

Comment: It gives `NoSuchElementException`

Comment: @NandanA there is no title or name of the window. How should I switch? I can try by index but then that's not good practice because there could be other tabs/windows open

Comment: Wondering why anyone wants to close it. It is not in the interest of the forum that you vote to close something that you don't answer to. It stops others also to try.