# Getting error while trying to locate a webelement - Python Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am new to Selenium. I am trying to find the locator for a textbox. However, I am getting "Element Not found" exception

Webpage: http://www.condos.ca

I am trying to find the locator for the "Search by Address" textbox. I have used the below XPATH's

- `//input[contains(@class,'react-')]`
- `//div[@id='autoComplete']/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/input`

When I checked these `xPath` on the Console, it finds the correct element. However, when I try to run it using my Selenium code, it throws an exception

Could anyone help? Thanks in advance

Comment: Those elements are located inside flex box. I am also new to this but found some questions and articles to handle these type of elements. You need to use selenium flex API to do this. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14619798/is-selenium-automation-tool-supports-flex-applications

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/automating-flex-application-selenium-webdriver-himanshu-tewari/

Please correct me if I am conveying anything wrong to the OP.

Comment: This is a similar question that I found on SO that is not answered yet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68914160/get-xpath-element-in-flexbox